# Is it tax fraud for an individual to declare non-taxable revenue as taxable income? (US tax laws)

Tags: united-states, fraud, money-laundering, federal-tax-law

Hypothetically, A wants to pay B a considerable amount of money.

In order to reduce the paper trail, A pays ***me*** the money and I transfer it to B.

To further obscure the paper trail, I declare the payment from A as income for work (non-existent) done by me for A, enter it on my US Income Tax return as taxable income, and pay the resulting tax.

I have submitted a false tax return, but it leads to an *increase* in tax paid.  Is it still a crime?

Edit: No money laundering.  A legally possesses  the money and has a perfectly legal (and very private) reason to pay it to B.

Comment: Money laundering is a different crime than tax fraud, but still a crime.

Comment: How do you know that your 20% tax bracket was greater than the tax bracket of person B? Either way this is a fraud against the US government. I would assume that they didn't want a paper trail because they have an outstanding debt like child support. Even if it wasn't money laundering it's still fraud.

Comment: What does B's tax bracket have to do with anything?  It's my taxes, with or without the fake income, that is of concern...

Comment: Why is it crucial to your scenario that you not report the income as miscellaneous income on Schedule 1; why do you have to classify it as *wages*?

Comment: "A legally possesses the money and has a perfectly legal (and very private) reason to pay it to B." - That is *not good enough.* Just evading reporting requirements is already structuring, a form of laundering, even if there is no underlying crime.

Comment: This seems like a rare non-tech example of the [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: @DJohnM B's tax bracket is relevant because you said this: "I have submitted a false tax return, but it leads to an *increase* in tax paid." It leads to an increase in tax paid **by you**, but may result in a reduction in the combined tax paid by you and B.

Comment: I do that same thing using a Donor Advised Fund.  I want to donate $50 to Charity X but don't want them spending $500 sending mooch letters every week for the next 10 years.  I tell my DAF to "donate $50 to this charity, and don't disclose my address".  Done.

Comment: @Kevin Step doctrine.  Only if the A->B direct move would be illegal.  Othewise IRS thanks you for the double taxation!

Comment: @AnthonyGrist that's difficult to imagine. Can you think of a scenario where OP's taxes would go up causing B's to go down (more)?  Not getting it.

Comment: @Harper: OP says he "transfers" to B, which stands in contrast to A "paying" him (wages).  That suggests B will not report the income as wages, but as a gift from OP (gift tax owed by OP if he runs out of lifetime gift exemption).

Comment: Sounds like a situation as: I have a close friend or relative that is in need of some money. I am able to give them money, but I don't want them to know that I was giving the money to them. So, I give the money to a middle person, and they find a way to give it to the final recipient.

Comment: @Harper "I do that same thing using a Donor Advised Fund." This is specifically authorized by statute and a donation to a DAF is disclosed to be for a third party. "Step doctrine. Only if the A->B direct move would be illegal." The step transaction doctrine can only be applied in favor of the IRS. "Can you think of a scenario where OP's taxes would go up causing B's to go down (more)? Not getting it." OP is in 20% bracket, B is in 35% bracket.

Comment: @Harper Perhaps it was poorly worded, but I'm suggesting that (tax paid by A on "income" + tax paid by B on transfer from A) is less than (tax paid by B on transfer from C). In that scenario, A paying more tax doesn't automatically mean that overall more tax is paid.

Answer (score 19):

**Money Laundering**

The primary crime that you have described is called [money laundering](https://fas.org/sgp/crs/misc/RL33315.pdf).

Note that money laundering includes: "structuring financial transactions in order to evade reporting requirements."

Unlike some other forms of money laundering, this does not require that the source of the funds be criminal, or that the actual transfer be criminal, so long as it is intended to avoid reporting requirements. Along the same lines is the even less obvious offense of [smurfing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structuring).

So, this does not cease to be money laundering because: "A legally possesses the money and has a perfectly legal (and very private) reason to pay it to B."

The transfer would typically have had to be reported on a Form W-2 (wage and salary income), a Form 1099 (most transfers that are usually taxable income), a Form 709 (gift tax return), a Form 1098 (mortgage interest), or 1040 Schedule A (deductible payments), or on a cash transaction form if conducted in that manner. The fact that you are reporting it as income, and that there would have been some disclosure requirement if paid to person B, implies that there is some reporting requirement that is avoided.

**Tax Crimes**

There are also [multiple tax related crimes](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-utl/tax_crimes_handbook.pdf) that could be implicated, not all of which require that taxes due by the person charged by reduced. *See, e.g*., Conspiracy to Defraud the United States (18 U.S.C. § 371); Attempts To Interfere With Administration of Internal Revenue Laws (I.R.C. § 7212); Fraudulent Returns, Statements or Other Documents (I.R.C. § 7207); Identity Theft (18 U.S.C. § 1028(a)(7)), etc.

Conspiracy to Defraud the United States, for example, is defined as follows:

> If two or more persons conspire either to commit any offense against
> the United States, or to defraud the United States, or any agency
> thereof in any manner or for any purpose, and one or more of such
> persons do any act to effect the object of the conspiracy, each shall
> be fined under this title or imprisoned not more than five years, or
> both.
>
> If, however, the offense, the commission of which is the object of the
> conspiracy, is a misdemeanor only, the punishment for such conspiracy
> shall not exceed the maximum punishment provided for such misdemeanor.f

"Conspiracy to defraud the government is a very broad concept." Tax Crimes Handbook at 132.

> Conspiracy to defraud the government is not limited to efforts to
> obtain money or property, but includes conspiracies where the object
> of the conspiracy is to obstruct, impair, interfere, impede or defeat
> the legitimate functioning of the government through fraudulent or
> dishonest means. Thus, conspiracy to defraud is not confined by
> reference to common law definitions of fraud. It is a separate crime
> to interfere with the lawful functions of the government without
> regard to the monetary consequences. Thus, § 371 involves both efforts
> to defraud the government of funds as well as interference with the
> lawful function of the government.
>
> The conspiracy to defraud prong
> of § 371 includes conspiracies to impede, impair, obstruct or defeat
> the lawful functions of the Treasury Department in the collection of
> income taxes. *United States v. Klein*, 247 F.2d 908, 915 (2d Cir.
> 1957), cert. denied, 355 U.S. 924 (1958). Arguments have been
> presented that § 371 was not intended to encompass conspiracies to
> violate the internal revenue laws or conspiracies to defraud the
> Service but these arguments have been rejected.
>
> Although decided in 1957, *Klein* is the leading case regarding
> conspiracies to impede and impair the Service and such conspiracies
> are commonly referred to as "Klein conspiracies." In *Klein* the
> defendants were acquitted of the tax evasion charges but were
> convicted on the conspiracy count. The wording of the conspiracy count
> read, in part, as follows: "... to defraud the United States by
> impeding, impairing, obstructing and defeating the lawful functions of
> the Department of the Treasury in the collection of the revenue; to
> wit, income taxes." In part, it was alleged in Klein that as "part of
> said conspiracy that **the defendants would conceal and continue to
> conceal the nature of their business activities and the source and
> nature of their income." The defendants concealed the source and
> nature of their income by** altering and making false entries in their
> books, **filing false income tax returns**, and providing false answers to
> interrogatories.
>
> Thus, a money laundering plan may result in a conspiracy to obstruct
> the Treasury. *United States v. Sanzo*, 673 F.2d 64, 69 (2d Cir.), cert.
> denied, 459 U.S. 858 (1982). In *Sanzo*, one defendant argued that there
> was no direct evidence that the other party to the plan would not
> report the laundered money or claim deductions. The court felt there
> was enough circumstantial evidence from which the jury could find that
> the defendant knew his accomplice would not report large sums of
> laundered money as income and that he would have to falsify business
> records to hide the laundering activities. *Sanzo*, 673 F.2d at 69.
> Note, it is not necessary to prove that the Service was actually
> impeded in its efforts to assess and collect the revenue.

Tax Crimes Handbook at 132-136 (in the pertinent parts, with most citations omitted).

**Caveat Regarding Legal Alternatives**

It is also worth noting that there are legal ways for person A to transfer money to person B without making it apparent, for example, in his check book or on his tax return that the funds were transferred to person B (exactly how is beyond the scope of this answer).

Generally speaking, they are distinguishable because the IRS is fully and accurately informed of what is going on in a way that the IRS is not allowed to disclose publicly.

But, the crude method used here does not achieve that end.

Comment: Some of those are quite a stretch.  Defraud the United States: Defraud is a verb that describes a practice of lying to someone or an institution to steal money specifically. It doesn't seem to apply to this question.

Comment: @Kevin Fegan  [18 USC 371](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/371) is quite broad, and "fraud" can mean any situation in which a false statement is mas to gain an advantage or to inflict harm. (18 USC 371 also covers conspiracy to commit an offense.) Making a false tax return in order to avoid criminal scrutiny could certainly could be considered an instance of fraud. If it results in a financial advantage, even more so. Other statutes including, 18 USC 1001, make any knowingly false statement in a tax return penalizable.

Comment: @KevinFegan Expanded answer to address this concern.

Comment: It's unfair that OP changed the question. But this new, dramatically expanded edit is doubling down when it should retreat.  It doesn't account for **OP flat-out stating the underlying transaction is legal, and that the motivation is privacy**.  That means all this about money-laundering, structuring and conspiracy is a fine answer *to a different question*. Privacy is a legitimate reason for this tactic, e.g. Mitt Romney giving money to OP to give to Sierra Club to keep from offending his political base.

Comment: @Harper: As a basic principle of law, someone asserting that a thing is legal doesn't make it legal. Anyway, the crime described by this answer is in the way the taxes are handled, not in the original transaction.

Comment: It is a crime to "conceal the nature of their business activities and the source and nature of their income" even if it is legal. Privacy is not a legal justification to make a false statement to a government agency (the IRS), absent express statutory exceptions (such as donor advised funds).

Answer (score 13):

> I have submitted a false tax return

Provided it really is false, you violate [18 USC 1001](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/1001):

> (a) Except as otherwise provided in this section, whoever, **in any matter within the jurisdiction of the executive,** legislative, or judicial **branch of the Government of the United States, knowingly and willfully—**
>
> (1) falsifies, conceals, or covers up by any trick, scheme, or device a material fact;
>
> (2) makes any materially false, fictitious, or fraudulent statement or representation; or
>
> (3) **makes or uses any false** writing or **document knowing the same to contain any materially false, fictitious, or fraudulent statement or entry;**
>
> shall be [sentenced in various ways]

It's "material" because it impacts the amount of tax you owe. The fact that it is detrimental to you is entirely irrelevant. Also, the exceptions in sections (b) and (c) are clearly inapplicable here, as neither applies to executive branch "matters" at all.

(There are numerous more specific laws that you probably also violated. I just wanted to ensure that it's *abundantly clear* that lying on your tax return is illegal, by some law or another, in almost any scenario you can imagine.)

Comment: The legislative or judicial prongs of (a) are highly relevant to illustrate that direct economic harm to the government isn't required.

Comment: Let me present a strawman.  There's a poster on another stack, who believes 100% of everything OP says is **canonical**.  He would say that since OP tossed out "false tax return", **every answer must worship that** and we must rigidly discard the fact that OP doesn't know what he's talking about.  I don't agree with that strawman.   I think "false tax return" is OP's weakest claim, and  the rest of the (edited) post does not support it.   Besides, you're allowed (required!!) to report "illegal income" and can simply claim the 5th.

Comment: @Harper: If the tax return contains any material, false statement, it violates the law. If it doesn't, it might or might not violate some other law, but that was not the question.

Comment: @Harper: This is not a tax law at all. It's a felony.

Comment: Yes, I see.  It's the one they used on Bill Clinton (about Lewinski) when they found nothing on Whitewater. I think its application in a tax case would be *violently dependent* on the underlying circumstances, about which OP has been silent so we can't know.  So I see your point; not knowing,  it's best to bring it up.

Comment: @Harper "you're allowed (required!!) to report "illegal income"" -- true "and can simply claim the 5th." - accurately reporting the illegal income to the extent required by non-criminal law may require you to waive the 5th Amendment privilege.

Comment: @ohwilleke no, that is settled law. Read up on that area of practice, it is interesting,

Answer (score 6):

### I don't think *any of it* is a crime

And it sounds like a lot of work to me.  Getting overpaid for it doesn't make you a crook, just one of many overpaid people in society today.

*Remember, you assure us this is legal, and the only part you are questioning is routing it through you.*

He can pay you money for any service, or to sleep on the job, or simply to abstain from something (classically: mistress hush money), except for certain illegal reasons. I haven't heard you state any evidence of an illegal reason, though there may be evidence you have not stated.

The only allusion of crime is you claiming "false tax return" and you could be wrong.  You're not a tax attorney.  *You aren't 100% sure* if the income is taxable or what even constitutes a false tax return. Be clear: **If in doubt, IRS wants you to declare the income**. You don't need to be super specific, in fact, IRS is looking for 2-3 word answers to detect filing errors, not a confession.

*Believe me, if they want to know, they'll ask*, but it's rare for IRS to chase details on declared income when they don't dispute the amount.

You might be under-reporting deductions, *but that's allowed*.  It's not illegal to *not know* every deduction you're allowed.  It's also perfectly legal to strategically skip or reduce a deduction. *

As a final catch-all, one can [report illegal income](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxation_of_illegal_income_in_the_United_States).  If you correctly invoke the 5th Amendment, this becomes a no-questions-asked bucket for reporting any dubious income. But IRS might leak your tax return to the police, who might then poke around.

Amusingly, one can even claim illegal expenses.

### We can exclude the *Step Transaction Doctrine*

If doing something in one step is illegal, and you do several steps that have the same effect, then the steps are illegal.

**You are assuring us that the single step is legal, so that means it is legal to split it into steps**. However, that does not automatically make each of the steps legal.

---

---

Examples.

You're [allowed to donate $2800](https://www.fec.gov/updates/contribution-limits-2019-2020/) to a candidate's primary election.  You give $2800 to a friend for him to donate to that same candidate. The "step trqnsaction doctrine" says that's the same as you giving $5600, and you are over limits!

You get $1,000,000 cash selling meth.  It's impossible to legally deposit the whole lump without explaining the source.  So you deposit $5000/day ([structuring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structuring)) or buy a car wash and sell washes to phantom customers  ([laundering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Money_laundering)).

Here's the exception that proves the rule.  Your income is too high to be eligible to contribute to a Roth IRA.  You contribute $5000 to a NDIRA (no income limits).  You *immediately* convert the NDIRA to a Roth (Income limits were removed in 2005).  That [was long thought](https://www.kitces.com/blog/dodging-the-income-limits-on-roth-contributions-strategy-or-abuse/) to be illegal because of the Step Transaction Doctrine, but  IRS and Congress have stated that it's OK.

*In the above example, the $1M is illegal because it's from meth.  If it was from a legal source you refuse to explain, it's not a crime but **they impound your money** whilst you still need to timely pay quarterly tax (1040ES) on it.  Ouch.*

---

* And I have personally tested that theory in tax court.  I reduced my  Schedule A deduction of state taxes to just below the AMT threshold. I also aimed to not pay tax on that much of next year's refund.  IRS lawyers cheerfully affirmed my entire plan was valid, and let me write it into the judge's order.

Comment: I'm not positive, but I don't think that depositing your 1,000,000$ is actually illegal.  Of course, making meth is (presumably) illegal, and that money might be illegal, since it's from an illegal act.  The deposit is probably going to get you investigated, but I don't think the amount is intrinsically illegal.  I think the illegal act would be depositing it in chunks of 5000$ to avoid being noticed.

Comment: @PatrickM It's illegal *without explaining the source*.

Comment: So you deposit the cash without explanation, the gov't a) seizes the money and b) pokes around looking for criminal activity. They never return it. To get it back you must sue, explain your source, and grind through the courts for years.  *But right now*, IRS wants quarterly 1040-ES taxes paid on it.  (And you don't have it).  To avoid paying tax on *every penny* you must be able to prove your deductible a) expenses and b) cost of goods sold. Which *again* means explaining the source.

Comment: True.  It's a terrible idea.  I was just pointing out that it's probably not technically illegal.  Just stupid.  You mention civil forfeiture, and it's likely they'll do that, but just because you can't prove the money is legal, doesn't mean you've committed a crime.

Comment: @PatrickM  Okay.  I buy that.  If everyone had forethought they would never, ever do this; however people often do things without considering consequences, and that's not a crime.

Comment: If as the question says, the return states that the money was payment from A to OP for specific work done, and that was knowingly false, that alone makes it a false return

Comment: The "step transaction doctrine" (it isn't called the step doctrine) is used to determine tax liability and doesn't automatically overcome a statutory crime's elements. Also there is no good faith reason to believe that you are correctly reporting the income in the OP when you know it is to conceal a payment to B.

Comment: So I fail to see what OP's option is, then, *Not* report the income???  You are operating out of a presumption of wrongdoing, when OP has flat out stated the underlying transaction is legal.   His "drama" over "false tax return" is one you should be rebutting, because an uneducated taxpayer *doesn't get to decide* whether a return is false or not.  David, returns don't state things like that.  There is no place on the form to write narrative, and IRS doesn't want it.  The ONLY question is "report, or not report".  Advising "not report" is a bold statement.

Comment: The OP stated that the motive was to "reduce the paper trail," apparently meaning not report to the government a transfer which is by law reportable. That is wrongdoing (if my understanding is correct) and the precise devices used will not help matters. Returns *do* state sources and purposes of payments, and often include explanatory notes. And I didn't say "don't report" I said "don't report falsely". OPs only legal options seem either decline the transaction, or disclose fully and accurately.

Comment: I don't think he meant "not report".  I think he meant "not report *the details of*"... Or perhaps "conceal the source". The people he aims to conceal it from *might not be the government*.  That is common in the nonprofit world.  And IRS isn't looking for a confessional, they're looking for 2 words.  If they want more, *don't worry, they'll ask*.  But it's rare to question income.

Comment: I downvote when i think an answer is not accurate or not helpful, or not sourced after a request for a source. I never DV unless the problem is described in a comment, either by me or someone else. I never DV based on who gave an answer. In this case the problem is "I don't think any of it is a crime" combined with a misunderstanding of the "step transaction" rule. If something illegal in one step is done through several, it is still illegal. But that does **not** mean things legal in one step always remain legal in multiple steps.

Comment: I add that you don't know who downvoted, unless someone says that they were the downvoter.

Comment: @DavidSiegel I didn't intend to say that about step transactions, but I see where you would infer it.  Fixed.  And I've elaborated more on why I doubt it's a crime, and further, **I gave him an exit-ramp if it is a crime**.  You forget about the right, nay obligation, to report illegal income.

Comment: While I still don't fully agree, you have removed what i think is the most obvious error, and I have removed my DV. I did recall the need to report illegal income, it was high in my thoughts. Most cases I nahve read of involving lies about income source that don't diminish tax paid involve reporting illegal income as from an untrue legal source; classic money laundering. OP said this is not that case, but not why the wish to concel the transaction

Comment: @DavidSiegel Thanks. He did say privacy, and that is a reasonable reason - I work in nonprofits where it can be an issue. I actually asked another question where the "privacy" question tangles up rather nastily with a step issue.  My view on illegal income is they don't send an auditing team of Blofeld, Lex Luthor and Charlie Madoff to audit whether your income is *actually* illegal.  In fact the 5th Amendment bars this!

Comment: "I fail to see what OP's option is, then, Not report the income?" One way to characterize it is as an irrevocable simple trust created by A for the benefit of B of which OP is the trustee, and report it on Form 1041. If OP is  instead acting as a nominee of A, then OP may need to issue a 1099 or W-2 from A without A's consent, since as a nominee or agent, OP isn't the true payor.

Comment: @Harper The 5th Amendment doesn't actually bar this. It gives you a choice. Decline to answer the tax questions that would incriminate you and suffer from the adverse inference in the tax arena that the result would be a bad one for you, or waive the 5th Amendment privilege and answer.

Comment: @ohwilleke when you declare illegal income it is necessary to also make a 5th Amendment declaration on your 1040.  I am not sure what bad result you would expect, other than what I stated. This sounds like handwringing.